# Sql join and count rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I'm trying to join two tables in order to count the data from a row in one of them.

`pin.id` and `repin.from_pin_id` are the primaries in two different tables.

I'm trying to count the number of rows a certain variable in `repin.from_pin_id` occurs where the `board_id` is equal to a certain variable ($boardDetails->id).
`board_id` is located in `pins`, which is why I'm trying to join `repin` to that table. It's the only way I can extract the specific board id.

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT repin.from_pin_id, pins.id COUNT(from_pin_id) FROM repin  WHERE from_pin_id = pins.id LEFT JOIN pins ON repin.from_pin_id = pins.id");
$countit = mysql_result($result, 0);
?>
```

Not having any luck.
I hope this comes across clearly, its hard to explain.

EDIT:

Here is the solution, I was struggling because I was mistakenly using the wrong field. Field `from_pin_id` should have been `owner_user_id`.

I took some of the suggestion queries and got it to work. Thanks guys.

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(owner_user_id) 
FROM repin  
INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = repin.from_pin_id 
WHERE owner_user_id='$boardDetails->user_id'
AND pins.board_id='$boardDetails->id'");
$countit = mysql_result($result, 0);
?>
```

Comment: How are not having any luck?  Does the statement give you the wrong results or do you get an error message and if so what error message?

Comment: Message: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: I've just had a look at the manual for [mysql_query](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) which says "For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error" and I'm guessing that there's something wrong with your select statement. Have you tried running it in a database query program? I think I see a missng comma in the list of columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this SQL instead I'm not familiar with  PHP so you may need to tweak the string handling a bit

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT 
    repin.from_pin_id, 
    pins.id, 
    COUNT(from_pin_id) 
FROM 
    repin  
    LEFT JOIN pins ON 
       repin.from_pin_id = pins.id
       AND " + $boardDetails->id +" =  pin.board_id 
GROUP BY 
    repin.from_pin_id, 
    pins.id 
");
$countit = mysql_result($result, 0);
?>
```

Comment: I think I explained incorrectly.
pin.id and repin.from_pin_id are the primaries in two different tables.
I'm trying to count the number of repin.from_pin_id where the board_id is equal to a certain variable ($boardDetails->id).
board_id is located in `pins`, which is why I'm trying to join repin to that table. It's the only way I can get the specific board.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, it looks like you want to be doing something like this:

```
SELECT repin.from_pin_id, pins.id, COUNT(from_pin_id) 
FROM repin 
    LEFT JOIN pins ON repin.from_pin_id = pins.id
GROUP BY repin.from_pin_id, pins.id
```

You don't need your `WHERE` clause -- that's handled in the `JOIN`.  And you need to add the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I think I explained incorrectly.
pin.id and repin.from_pin_id are the primaries in two different tables.
I'm trying to count the number of repin.from_pin_id where the board_id is equal to a certain variable ($boardDetails->id).
board_id is located in `pins`, which is why I'm trying to join repin to that table. It's the only way I can get the specific board.

Answer (score 1):

can you try with the below code and you missed a `comma` in between `pin.id and count`

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT repin.from_pin_id, pins.id,COUNT(from_pin_id) FROM repin  INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = repin.from_pin_id WHERE pins.board_id='".$boardDetails->id."'");
$countit = mysql_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: I think I explained incorrectly.
pin.id and repin.from_pin_id are the primaries in two different tables.
I'm trying to count the number of repin.from_pin_id where the board_id is equal to a certain variable ($boardDetails->id).
board_id is located in `pins`, which is why I'm trying to join repin to that table. It's the only way I can get the specific board.